# Is it possible that I can upload adobe brackets to cloud and use it as our own cloud code editor?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Well it might sound wired but is there a a chance as the brackets is all HTML CSS JS code editor. I tried to look at the core but there is too much going on. So if someone had already found out. Please share.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no turnkey solution, but the pieces are there if you want to build an online code editor based on Brackets:

***Update:*** There's now a [Brackets in-browser documentation page](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-in-Browser) that includes all this info plus far more detail.

- The [FileSystem backend is pluggable](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/File-System-Implementations), so you can replace the local disk IO with a layer that talks to your server (or talks to the Dropbox API, etc.). But you need to define that backend storage mechanism based on your webapp's specific needs.
- The [in-browser-filesystem branch](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/compare/master...pflynn;in-browser-file-system) includes a dummy FileSystem backend and stubs out the remaining desktop-app-specific functionality. So you can checkout this branch and point any simple localhost server at it to run the main "index.html" in browser. (That branch is a bit old, however - it doesn't have all the latest Brackets features).
- Then you can swap in your real storage backend (from the first bullet) in place of the dummy layer. You may also want to build signin/auth infrastucture, etc.
- Some Brackets features are disabled in-browser, including Live Preview and Extension Manager. We haven't yet thought through how things like that would work in-browser. But all the core code-editing features are there.
- The in-browser branch may also have some bugs & layout glitches on non-WebKit browsers.

Some people have already used Brackets as the basis to build a web-based code editor, so there may be an opportunity to collaborate with them or reuse their code. Examples include:

- [Mozilla Nimble](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Webmaker/Concept-Nimble) project - still in the experimental stage. [Online demo here](http://humphd.github.io/brackets/src/).
- [Treehouse Workspaces](http://teamtreehouse.com/workspaces) (requires subscription?)